# Control the existency of constant in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file, constants

I have a file named config.php, content:

```
define ('CLIENT_ID', 'foo');
```

I have a file named requiredconstants.php, content:

```
$aRequiredConstants = array (
'CLIENT_ID',
);
```

Now, I want to check, in index.php, if every value from $aRequiredConstants is defined

print_r of $aRequiredConstants returns

```
array (
[0] => 'CLIENT_ID',
)
```

echo CLIENT_ID returns foo

but when I try

```
foreach($aRequiredConstants as $key => $value)
if(!defined($value))
    echo "NOT DEFINED";
```

It returns NOT DEFINED.. but why? It IS defined.

Comment: you sure you have the file with the defined constant included? I tried your code and it's not printing NOT DEFINED which means it's defined.

Comment: Make sure that you have included both config.php and requiredconstants.php in index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works just fine:

```
<?php
define('have', 2);
$a = array('have', 'not');
foreach($a as $v) {
    if( defined($v) ) {
        echo $v . ' is OK'."\n";
    } else {
        echo $v . ' is NOT'."\n";
    }
}
```